# assembly intel x86 Structures, and receiving structures as an arguement

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

Those of you who prowl over the assembly posts would notice I've been posting quite a bit while trying to figure out assembly, each time learning something new.

I've been busy working c code into assembly and running a small test to see if I get the same results. The next bit of c code I'm translating has structs, and I can't seem to find any good, complete example to follow for this.

Here is my C code:

```
typedef struct item {
    int  number;
    char name[32];
} item;

/**
 * Performs a binary sort on the items pointed to by the parameter list.
 *
 * @param[in/out]   list  pointer to an array of items
 * @param[in]       n     total number of elements in the array
 */

void binary_sort_c(item *list, int n) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int bottom;
    int top;
    int middle;
    item temp;

    if (list != NULL) { 
        i = 1;
        while (i < n) {
            temp = list[i];
            bottom = 0;
            top = i-1;
            while (bottom <= top) {
                middle = (bottom+top)/2;
                if (temp.number < list[middle].number) {
                    top = middle-1;
                } else {
                    bottom = middle+1;
                }
            }
            j = i-1;
            while (j >= bottom) {
                list[j+1] = list[j];
                j = j-1;
            }
            list[bottom] = temp;
            i = i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here lies my problem, I can't seem to figure out how to use this structure in assembly. Would I need to remake the structure in assembly if it's passed as an argument to the assembly by the c code?

How would I access the different elements in the structure in assembly? 
For example, `temp.number`

How can I check if `list = NULL` in assembly?

A little example code that I could use as a template to work from and understand would be perfect.

Comment: `list` is just a simple pointer argument, so you check for NULL as usual by comparing to zero. As for accessing members, you need to know the offsets.

Comment: @Jester so would this suffice to check `if (list != NULL) `, `mov eax, list`, `cmp eax, 0` `jne LABEL`?

Comment: Yes that would work, depending on how `list` was declared.

Comment: I wonder what exactly you mean by `mov eax,list`. In NASM that will load value of `list` symbol into eax. If that symbol was defined as `list dd 0`, eax will contain address of that zero, not the zero itself. So in such case you have to do `mov eax,[list]  test eax,eax  jz detected_null`. If `list` was defined as global variable `item *list = nullptr;` in C, then again `mov eax,list` is loading address of that pointer (`&list`), not it's `nullptr` value. So `mov eax,list` doesn't make sense to me?

Answer (score 1):

> How would I access the different elements in the structure in assembly?

You would need to know the exact memory layout the C compiler generates for that struct (i.e. if and how it aligns/pads elements).

Assuming a packed struct you should be able to do something like:

```
STRUC ITEM
.iNumber RESD 1
.cName RESB 32
ENDSTRUC

; Now let's say you have an item* in ebx:

mov dword [ebx + ITEM.iNumber],123
```

Comment: Like you did here, could I take the arguments given as paramenters and access them using that?
Like: `mov edi, list,   
 mov eax, 1, 
 lea esi, [edi+eax*4] ;,
 mov ebx, [esi],
 mov ecx, dword[ebx+ ITEM.iNumer]`
Would this work? @Michael

Comment: Also, would `STRUC ITEM,
.iNumber RESD 1,
.cName RESB 32,
ENDSTRUC` 
go before or after 
`binary_sort:
 push ebp, 
 mov ebp, esp,`
@Michael

Comment: The struct type definition can go either before or after the location where you first use it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can the struct have an element inside it that refers to a pointer to another struct of the same type? how would I do this in asm? Similar to `item *next`

Comment: That would just be a DWORD (or QWORD on x86-64).

Comment: How could I initialize `item temp;` in assembly using this struct?

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html search for "4.11.10 STRUC and ENDSTRUC: Declaring Structure Data Types" ... you can allocate uninitialized memory for item by `resb struct_name_size`, but to init it's values, you have to either copy some "init state memory image" there, or write value by value in code resembling C++ constructor. Or use "istruc" macro as described in next chapter 4.11.11